# How to use bell character (BEL, CTRL-G, \x07) with xterm.js?

Tags: xtermjs

How do I add use the bell character with Xterm.js?  I see a couple of entries in the sources 'options' defaults, but dont get anything whether i send it from the shell or write it directly to the terminal, even with those set to true.  I tried overloading the term.bell function with one containing a window.navigator.vibrate, and that works if I call it directly, but doesnt fire in response to a bell character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  So testing determined nothing is blocking the bell character ("\x07" or "\u0007") from getting through to xterm.js.  It just doesnt respond, even if you enable the flags in the options.  The code in the source looks like it should work, but something internal is not connected.  Since I am avoiding actual changes to the source to make upgrades to xterm.js straightforward and out of the box, I worked a little magic.  Here's a hack to get the bell character working:

Make a function that fires on the "message" event from your websocket.  In it, check for a match for BEL.  Then have it do your voodoo if it detects it.  Something like:

```
sock.addEventListener('message',function(v){  if(v.match(/\x07/)){ /*voodoo here*/ }  });
```

Where v is event, \x07 is BEL, and voodoo is code or an invocation to blip the screen white briefly, make a chirp, vibrate if your getting around on "mobile", or open a portal to the single-sock dimension.

Annoyingly, now I need to look up more ansi codes and find a pattern, as some end in a BEL character.  So this will work by itself, but will be set off by some codes not intended to act as BEL, because they contain that character.  More on this later....

FYI, not sure if this works with term.attach().  I have my own thing that does some preprocessing anyway, so basically all I had to do was splice in the if/match, but cut that out, the above code is the minimal cut-paste version.

Hope this helps someone else.  Bug out.

[image][image]

Comment: `xterm.write('\x07')` currently _does_ make a sound, given options `{ bellStyle: 'sound' }`.

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I would think so.  At the time of asking, the structure was there but it was empty, no audio object or anything to make it play.  But the ability to do something in response to \x07 was there.  Mind you, I was working with the npm installed version.